# find the overlap between two strings

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string and need to check with and get whether the following strings overlap with the start and end of my target string:

- target string: "click on the Run"
- search strings: "the Run button to", "code and click on"

Apparently:

- **"the Run button to"** is overlapped at the **end of target "click on the Run"**
- **"code and click on"** is overlapped at the **start of target "click on the Run"**

Both, "the Run" and "click on" will be the desired results.

I have come up with a function to check and get the overlapped results for the cases at the start and at the end separately.

Question:

But my code could not be able to get the expected results only if I know how the search string overlapped with the target string in the very first place. And how can I combine the searched results in one go as well?

```js
function findOverlapAtEnd(a, b) {
  if (b.length === 2) {
    return "";
  }

  if (a.indexOf(b) >= 0) {
    return b;
  }

  if (a.endsWith(b)) {
    return b;
  }

  return findOverlapAtEnd(a, b.substring(0, b.length - 1));
}

function findOverlapAtStart(a, b) {
  if (b.length === 2) {
    return "";
  }

  if (a.indexOf(b) >= 0) {
    return b;
  }

  if (a.startsWith(b)) {
    return b;
  }

  return findOverlapAtStart(a, b.substring(1));
}

console.log(findOverlapAtEnd("click on the Run", "the Run button to"))
console.log(findOverlapAtStart("click on the Run", "code and click on"))
```

---

edited:

case in the middle is also considered, e.g.:

- target string: "click on the Run"
- search strings: "on the"
- Return value: "on the"

Comment: How many characters minimum to count as an overlap?  I'm curious enough to try to write this code, but it's seeming like it will be pretty complex because you need to loop through a lot of possible combinations.

Comment: Seems you get the problem ! Yes, definitely it is pointless if we take 1 as an minimum. So that's why I set the base case as 2. I take 2 as minimum just because I guess it is enough to believe it is an valid overlapped. Just think of the target set and search set are from an article. They are an highlight from the article

Comment: I just tried again, possibly 2 is not enough... i just took 5 again

Comment: Do you consider the situation when the overlap is in the middle, e.g., `target="hello hello world world"` and `b="hello world"`?

Comment: yes, it is also included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
function findOverlapAtEnd(a, b, min) { 
  if (b.length <= min) {
    return '';
  }

  if (a.indexOf(b) >= 0) {
    return b;
  }

  if (a.endsWith(b)) {
    return b;
  }

  return findOverlapAtEnd(a, b.substring(0, b.length - 1), min);
}

function findOverlapAtStart(a, b, min) {
  if (b.length <= min) {
    return '';
  }

  if (a.indexOf(b) >= 0) {
    return b;
  }

  if (a.startsWith(b)) {
    return b;
  }

  return findOverlapAtStart(a, b.substring(1), min);
}

const GetOverlappingSection = (target, search, min) => {
  if (target.length < search.length) {
    const tmp = target;
    target = search;
    search = tmp;
  }
  let overlap1 = findOverlapAtStart(target, search, min);
  if (overlap1.length === 0) {
    overlap1 = findOverlapAtEnd(target, search, min);
  }
  return overlap1;
};

const removeEmptyKeyword = overlap => {
  let tmpFinaloverlap = [];
  overlap.forEach((key, idx) => {
    if (!(key.trim().length === 0)) {
      tmpFinaloverlap = [...tmpFinaloverlap, key];
    }
  });
  return tmpFinaloverlap;
};

// let overlap = ['click on','the Run']

const GetOverlappingOfKeyowrd1And2 = (keywordSet1, keywordSet2,min) => {
  let resultSetoverlap = [];
  let tmpresultSetoverlap = [];
  keywordSet1.forEach(key =>
    keywordSet2.forEach(k2 => {
      tmpresultSetoverlap = [
        ...tmpresultSetoverlap,
        GetOverlappingSection(key, k2, min),
      ];
    })
  );
  // get the resultSetoverlap
  tmpresultSetoverlap.forEach(element => {
    if (element.length > 0) {
      resultSetoverlap = [...resultSetoverlap, element];
    }
  });
  return resultSetoverlap;
};

const min = 2;


//To handle overlapping issue in overlapping set, that casuing 
overlap.forEach((key, idx) => {
  if (idx < overlap.length - 1) {
    for (let i = idx + 1; i < overlap.length; i++) {
      console.log(`key: ${key}`);
      console.log(`search: ${overlap[i]}`);
      let overlapSection = GetOverlappingSection(key, overlap[i], min);
      if (overlapSection.length > 0) {
        console.log(`overlapSection: ${overlapSection}`);
        overlap[idx] = overlap[idx].replace(overlapSection, '');
      }
    }
  }
});

overlap = removeEmptyKeyword(overlap);

console.log(overlap);

overlap.forEach(key => {
  keywordSet2 = keywordSet2.map((k1, idx) => {
    console.log(`checking overlap keyword:'${key}' in '${k1}'`);
    return k1.replace(key, '');
  });
});

overlap.forEach(key => {
  keywordSet1 = keywordSet1.map((k1, idx) => {
    console.log(`checking overlap keyword:'${key}' in '${k1}'`);
    return k1.replace(key, '');
  });
});

keywordSet2 = removeEmptyKeyword(keywordSet2);
keywordSet1 = removeEmptyKeyword(keywordSet1);

overlap.forEach(key => {
  text = text.replace(key, `$#k1k2$&$`);
});
keywordSet1.forEach(key => {
  text = text.replace(key, `$#k1$&$`);
});
keywordSet2.forEach(key => {
  text = text.replace(key, `$#k2$&$`);
});

console.log(`ResultSetoverlap after processing:${text}`);
```

Comment: This works without any bug and even consider the minimum length  of overlap

Answer (score 1):

Because I need to decompress and I find these logic puzzles fun, here's my solution to the problem...

https://highdex.net/begin_end_overlap.htm

You can view source of the page to see JavaScript code I used.  But just in case I ever take that page down, here's the important function...

```
function GetOverlappingSection(str1, str2, minOverlapLen = 4) {
    var work1 = str1;
    var work2 = str2;
    var w1Len = work1.length;
    var w2Len = work2.length;
    var resultStr = "";
    var foundResult = false;
    var workIndex;
    
    if (minOverlapLen < 1) { minOverlapLen = 1; }
    else if (minOverlapLen > (w1Len > w2Len ? w2Len : w1Len)) { minOverlapLen = (w1Len > w2Len ? w2Len : w1Len); }
    
    //debugger;
    
    //we have four loops to go through.  We trim each string down from each end and see if it matches either end of the other string.
    for (var i1f = 0; i1f < w1Len; i1f++) {
        workIndex = work2.indexOf(work1);
        if (workIndex == 0 || (workIndex != -1 && workIndex == w2Len - work1.length)) { 
            //we found a match!
            foundResult = true;
            resultStr = work1;
            break;
        }
        
        work1 = work1.substr(1);
        if (work1.length < minOverlapLen) { break; }
    }

    
    if (!foundResult) { 
        //debugger;
    
        //reset the work vars...
        work1 = str1;
        
        for (var i1b = 0; i1b < w1Len; i1b++) {
            workIndex = work2.indexOf(work1);
            if (workIndex == 0 || (workIndex != -1 && workIndex == w2Len - work1.length)) { 
                //we found a match!
                foundResult = true;
                resultStr = work1;
                break;
            }
            
            work1 = work1.substr(0, work1.length - 1);
            if (work1.length < minOverlapLen) { break; }
        }
    }
    
    if (!foundResult) {
        //debugger;
    
        //reset the work vars...
        work1 = str1;
        
        for (var i2f = 0; i2f < w2Len; i2f++) {
            workIndex = work1.indexOf(work2);
            if (workIndex == 0 || (workIndex != -1 && workIndex == w1Len - work2.length)) { 
                //we found a match!
                foundResult = true;
                resultStr = work2;
                break;
            }
            
            work2 = work2.substr(1);
            if (work2.length < minOverlapLen) { break; }
        }
    }
    
    if (!foundResult) {
        //debugger;
    
        //reset the work vars...
        work2 = str2;
        
        for (var i2b = 0; i2b < w2Len; i2b++) {
            workIndex = work1.indexOf(work2);
            if (workIndex == 0 || (workIndex != -1 && workIndex == w1Len - work2.length)) { 
                //we found a match!
                foundResult = true;
                resultStr = work2;
                break;
            }
            
            work2 = work2.substr(0, work2.length - 1);
            if (work2.length < minOverlapLen) { break; }
        }
    }
    
    return resultStr;
}
```

Hopefully that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and glad that you found it interesting as me. I just made a quite check. It didnt pass the case that for overlapping the in the middle. eg.  String #1:click on the Run ;String #2:on the